# How to toupper char array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, toupper

whats wrong here?

I want to check if the char in char array islower, so if it is it should be changed in uppercase.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char arr[100];
    scanf("%s",&arr);
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(arr);i++){
        if(int islower(arr[i])){
            arr[i] = toupper(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to test if lowercase first. `toupper` won't do anything unless there is something to do.

Comment: What's up with the syntax: `if(int islower(arr[i]))...`? Why the `int`? Also, note that `toupper` will return the same character back again if there's no upper case equivalent (read the documentation!). So you don't need the `if` statement at all.

Comment: What's wrong with your code ? What does not work ?

Comment: You're accessing uninitialized elements of the array. You should limit the loop to `strlen(arr)`, not `sizeof(arr)`.

Comment: Using `scanf("%s", &arr);` is wrong on 3 counts: (1) you should limit the input (`"%99s"`), (2) you should not use `&` because it passes a `char (*)[100]` where a `char *` is expected, and (3) you should check that `scanf()` reports a return value of 1 before using the result.

Comment: The loop condition on `for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)` avoids stepping out of bounds of the array, but it means that you're processing data not set by `scanf()` in general.  You should establish the length of the data read by `scanf()` and only process that data in the loop (`int len = strlen(arr);` and then `for (i = 0; i < len; i++)`).  You should print a newline after the string, too: `printf("%s\n", arr);`.

Comment: "*whats wrong here?* it does not compile. Line 7: `error: expected expression before ‘int’` .. at least! :-/

Comment: You might just like to remove the stray `int` in line 7,  .. at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To measure the length of a string properly, use `strlen`, not `sizeof`

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++){ // Don't use sizeof on this line
```

---

Here's a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char arr[100];
    scanf("%s", arr);

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++){
        arr[i] = toupper(arr[i]);
    }

    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Or even:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char arr[100];
    scanf("%s", arr);

    for(char* c=arr; *c=toupper(*c); ++c) ;

    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an include `#include <ctype.h>`

Also you don't need your  `if` statement. [`toupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) takes care of that internally (if you really want to keep `islower` remove the `int` in your `if` statement).

Answer (score 1):

Add the header that declares `islower` and `toupper`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

In addiition,

```
    if(int islower(arr[i])){
```

is not right. Remove the `int`.

```
    if(islower(arr[i])){
```

Answer (score 1):

*whats wrong here?*

The line: `if(int islower(arr[i])){` fails compile for bad expression.
Change to: `if(islower(arr[i])){`

And in this line in your code may be looking beyond where it should:

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(arr);i++){
```

as you may be looking at space past the string terminator:

```
|s|t|r|i|n|g|\0|<unknown contents here, part of your legal memory, but are not part of the string>
```

it *should* be:

```
int len = strlen(arr);
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
```